# Django-haystack without attribute '_fields'

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm making my blog on Django and I want to add site search based on django-haystack. I made a basic configuration of haystack, using official manuals, but when I want to test my search, I'm getting an error: 'Options' object has no attribute '_fields'

Here are some of my configs:

search_indexes.py

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

So this is my problem. Does anyone worked with smth similar? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the traceback

Comment: http://dpaste.com/1553389/ here it is

Comment: I do have same problem. My django form.py is working fine in 1.4.1 but when I upgraded to 1.6.1. I encountered your problem, that was yesterday. My traceback telling me I have a problem with this line `for model_field in SOA_detail._meta._fields():`

Comment: I also upgrated Django to 1.6.1, and got the same error. Do I need to downgrade Django to 1.4?

Or, maybe, do I need to edit haystack code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are hitting a bug in the simple backend which is [fixed in git](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/commit/49564861e432ec3c4b8d13d3d4ce8eda763d1308). There doesn't seem to be a release which contains this fix, though, so you can either upgrade to the development version:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git@master#egg=django-haystack
```

Or use a different backend (elasticsearch, solr, ...)